# Running custom C# middeware after authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-middleware

In my `Program.cs` I have

```
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.MapControllers();
                cfg.MapFallbackToController("Get", "Branding");
            });
```

with the expectation that my custom middleware would run after authentication and therefore I would have a claims identity to play with.

But when my `MyCustomMiddleware.Invoke` is called the `_next` is `AuthorizationMiddleware` as expeted, but the `context.User` is not authenticated and has no claims.

However, the `context.User` *is* authenticated and has claims *after* `_next.Invoke(context)` returns.

So it looks like the middleware is running out of order.

What could be wrong?!

Comment: I tried as you mentioned,but if I logined  successfully, context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in my middleware after app.UseAuthentication() will  be true,did you really login successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the behaviour you are seeing is correct if the `AuthenticationMiddleware` has yet to complete authenticating the user. Depending on your selected authentication scheme, the `AuthenticationMiddleware` may have returned back a HTTP 401 Challenge response to the client, or a HTTP 301 redirect to send the user to the authentication provider's login page if using OAuth. Check the `context.Response` inside of your middleware to be sure that this is in fact what is happening.

If the `AuthenticationMiddleware` hasn't short circuited the middleware, the unauthenticated request will still be passed on to the subsequently registered middleware before the response is sent back to the client.

Typically, its recommended that the `AuthorizationMiddleware` is ordered immediately after the `AuthenticationMiddleware` (see: [ASP.NET Core Fundamentals Built-in Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#built-in-middleware)), so that the user is properly authenticated and claims have been added. Because you have chosen to put a middleware in between, you are seeing the in-between process that ASP.NET core is following to authenticate and provide claims for the user.